# items.add, visual studio throws an error saying it has "no usable extension"

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, syntax, calculator

here's the lines and usage that are giving me fits, mainly the *item.add* is my main error

[image: Error]

OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

```
        openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

        string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
        string line = "";

        int sum = 0;
        int numberCount = 0;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lstNumbers.**Items.Add(line);**

            sum = sum + int.Parse(line);

            numberCount++;
        }
        fileListBox.Text = "Total Numbers are " + numberCount + Environment.NewLine + V + sum;
    }

    private static void NewMethod(string line) =>
```

lstNumber**s.Items.Add(line);**
    }

```
internal class lstNumbers
{
    internal static object Items;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the entire snippet?

Comment: {
                lstNumbers.Items.Add(line);

                sum = sum + int.Parse(line);

                numberCount++;
            }
            fileListBox.Text = "Total Numbers are " + numberCount + Environment.NewLine + V + sum;
        }

        private static void NewMethod(string line) => lstNumbers.Items.Add(line);
    }

    internal class lstNumbers
    {
        internal static object Items;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things, if you're using extension method:

1. Extension method should be made Public.
2. You have to use 'this' keyword for the parameters.

   public static int WordCount(this string str){.....}